# Iterate Table result to different divs with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, iteration, each

Using this code....trying to get the result from each multiple table and target the result to a div that has the same class...one result from each table to each div....without adding any id's etc....and not using .after().  Hope that makes sense.  You can see some console.logs I have set up...but can't seem to get it to populate the divs with the correct results.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

//Get Number of Divs with class='sum'
var divN = $( ".sum" ).length;
console.log('Number of Divs in page that match class sum : ' + divN);

//Get Number of TDs with class='two'
var tdN = $( ".two" ).length;
console.log('Number of TDs in page that match class two : ' + tdN);

//Get Number of Tables
var tblN = $( "table" ).length;
console.log('Number of Tables in page : ' + tblN);

//Get Number of TDs with class='two' in each table
$("table").each(function(){
tblSum = $('.two', this).length;
console.log('Number of TDs that match class two in each Table : ' + tblSum);
});

//Get result from each table and place it in div class="sum"
$(".sum").text(tblSum);
});

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<table>
        <tr><td class="one">Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="one">Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="one two">Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="one">Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="one">Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="one two">Test</td></tr>

</table>
<div class="sum"></div>
<table>
        <tr><td class="one">Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="one">Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="one two">Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="one">Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="one">Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="one">Test</td></tr>

</table>
<div class="sum"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: How do I get the result from each multiple table and target the result to a div that has the same class...one result from each table to each div....without adding any id's etc....and not using .after().  Result of table 1 should go to the first occurrence of the div with a class="sum".  The second table result should go to the second occurrence of the div with class="sum".  Trying to figure out how I can accomplish this.

Comment: What you mean by the word `result` ?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `next()` function like :

```
$(this).next('.sum').text(tblSum);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table").each(function() {
    var tblSum = $('.two', this).length;
    $(this).next('.sum').text(tblSum);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one two">Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one two">Test</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<div class="sum"></div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one two">Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">Test</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<div class="sum"></div>
```